# Convert the response to Flux ignoring certain fields of the response Json

Tags: json, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Using the Spring WebClient I am calling a Rest API that gives me a response as a JSON, following is a structure of the response -

```
{
   "vehicles":[
        { "name":"veh1", "type":"car", "age": 5 },
        { "name":"veh2", "type":"speedboat", "age":12},
        .....
   ]
   "metadata": {
        "token":"abcd",
        "days":120
   }
}
```

I am a newbie to reactive programming, I have written the following code, which works fine ..

```
Mono<VehicleResponse> = webclient.get()
                        .uri("/legacy/vehicles")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .retrieve()
                        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.empty()) 
                        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.empty()) 
                        .bodyToMono(VehicleResponse.class);
```

But, actually what I am interested in is, only the vehicles array (don't want the metadata information.) Is it possible to obtain / read only the vehicles (array) as a Flux of Vehicle ?

Comment: you have to write a custom json serializer and insert this into jackson, and tbh, thats a lot more work then just having a class that contains a list and then do `.flatmap(vehicleResponse -> { return Flux.fromIterable(vehicleResponse.getVehicles()); })`